# Interacting with and rendering a react component locally

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have some component that renders an svg element. I'd like to get a bunch of static image files corresponding to the generated svg elements, with various property settings. e.g. something like...

```
for (let i=0; i < 100; i++) {
  let foo = <Foo bar={i} />;
  foo.render(); // ???
  fs.writeFile(`foo_${i}.svg`, foo.outerHTML);
}
```

I can create such a script and try to run it with node, but I created my project with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) which uses a bunch of features not supported by node (like es6 imports).

Is there some other js engine I can use to run this code locally, or some easy way to hook in to the transpiling settings used by create-react-app?

There are some docs relating to [pre-rendering static HTML](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#pre-rendering-into-static-html-files), but the use case is quite different. I'm not trying to pre-render my site for performance reasons, I'm just trying to render one particular component, constructed with some particular props.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Webpack with Babel which will transpile ES6 to ES5. Also, webpack v2 natively supports ES6 Import statement.

After this build , your node server can easily serve the generated bundle file.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do I need to install / what commands do I need to run before I can run my script?